# Разбить HTML на элементы в массиве

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Делаю парсер информации с одного сайта.
Нужную информацию спарсил, но теперь не могу разбить эту информацию на элементы в массиве.

Кусок кода, который спарсил:

```
<div id="score-data">

    <h4>АВСТРАЛИЯ И ОКЕАНИЯ</h4>

        <span>19:00</span>
        Бангладеш - Таиланд 
        <a href="/match/CIzqg8pj/" class="sched">1:2</a>

        <br>

        <span>19:00</span>
        Восточный Тимо - ОАЭ  
        <a href="/match/xI35TlM2/" class="sched">1:1</a>

        <br>

        <span>19:00</span>
        Пакистан - Япония
        <a href="/match/j9ZnhSad/" class="sched">1:8</a>

        <br>

    <h4>Кубок Венесуэлы</h4>

        <span>15:00</span>
        Каракас - Трухильяно 
        <a href="/match/vZaLKcfM/" class="sched">3:1</a>

        <br>

        <span>18:30</span>
        Португеза - Эстудиантес  
        <a href="/match/YeaPJH9S/" class="sched">2:2</a>
</div>
```

По итогу из этого куска нужно сделать вот такой массив:

```
$array = [
    ['championship' => 'АВСТРАЛИЯ И ОКЕАНИЯ', 'teams' => 'Бангладеш - Таиланд', 'result'   => '1:2'],
    ['championship' => 'АВСТРАЛИЯ И ОКЕАНИЯ', 'teams' => 'Восточный Тимо - ОАЭ', 'result'   => '1:1'],
    ['championship' => 'АВСТРАЛИЯ И ОКЕАНИЯ', 'teams' => 'Пакистан - Япония', 'result'   => '1:8'],
    ['championship' => 'Кубок Венесуэлы', 'teams' => 'Каракас - Трухильяно', 'result'   => '3:1'],
    ['championship' => 'Кубок Венесуэлы', 'teams' => 'Португеза - Эстудиантес', 'result'   => '2:2'],
];
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите как реализовать идею? 
Знаю что нужно делать через регулярки, но не понимаю как.

p.s. Дико извиняюсь, вопрос отредактировал, неконкретно указал необходимый результат.

Comment: Каким образом у вас в результате получается 3:1, если в исходном коде нет такого?

Comment: И нужно ли вам записывать все счета команды в разное время?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: @АртемСмирнов, вас решение устраивает?

Comment: @Let's say Pie, низкий поклон, работает как надо) Сейчас буду разбираться, что да как в коде всё устроено. Целый день возился с регулярками для решения, но ничего не вышло.

Comment: @АртемСмирнов, будут вопросы, пишите, хд)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повозился часик, но сделал, все работает, слегка велосипед, но все же работает, хд.

Само решение включает в себя использование регулярных выражений, хотя изначально хотел использовать библиотеку `DOM` для парсинга, но появились некоторые проблемы.

Изначально имеем такие входные данные:

```
$string = '<div id="score-data">

<h4>АВСТРАЛИЯ И ОКЕАНИЯ</h4>

    <span>19:00</span>
    Бангладеш - Таиланд 
    <a href="/match/CIzqg8pj/" class="sched">1:2</a>

    <br>

    <span>19:00</span>
    Восточный Тимо - ОАЭ  
    <a href="/match/xI35TlM2/" class="sched">1:1</a>

    <br>

    <span>19:00</span>
    Пакистан - Япония
    <a href="/match/j9ZnhSad/" class="sched">1:8</a>

    <br>

<h4>Кубок Венесуэлы</h4>

    <span>15:00</span>
    Каракас - Трухильяно 
    <a href="/match/vZaLKcfM/" class="sched">3:1</a>

    <br>

    <span>18:30</span>
    Португеза - Эстудиантес  
    <a href="/match/YeaPJH9S/" class="sched">2:2</a>
</div>';
```

Далее идет само решение, которое я подкорректировал с момента отправления ответа:

```
preg_match_all('~<div id="score-data">(.+)</div>~s', $string, $matches);
preg_match_all('~<h4>(.+?)</h4>~', $matches[1][0], $match);

$data = array_filter(preg_split('~<h4>(.+?)</h4>~', $matches[1][0]), 'trim');

foreach ($data as $G => $K)
{
    preg_match_all('~<span>([^<]+)</span>([^<]+)<a[^>]+>([^<]+)~', 
        $data[$G], $pregs, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    $flix[] = $pregs;
}

foreach ($flix as $c => $keys) {
    $cont[$match[1][$c]] = $keys;
}

foreach ($cont as $key => $value)
{
    $dataContent[] = array_map(function ($x) use ($key) {
        return [
            'championship' => $key,
            'teams' => trim($x[2]), 
            'time' => $x[1], 
            'result' => $x[3]
        ];
    }, $cont[$key]);
}

foreach ($dataContent as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $x) {
        $array[] = $x;
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

Получаем нужный нам результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [championship] => АВСТРАЛИЯ И ОКЕАНИЯ
            [teams] => Бангладеш - Таиланд
            [time] => 19:00
            [result] => 1:2
        )

        ...

    [4] => Array
        (
            [championship] => Кубок Венесуэлы
            [teams] => Португеза - Эстудиантес
            [time] => 18:30
            [result] => 2:2
        )

)
```

Я так же добавил в решение переменную `time`, на всякий случай, мало ли понадобится.

> **Важно**: я не уверен, что мое решение самое оптимальное, и все еще
>   склонен к тому, чтобы реализовать это с помощью библиотеки `DOM`.